# System.Data.SQLite: "parameters not allowed in view", how to protect against SQL injection?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, sql-injection, sql-view

I'm writing a C# app with an SQLite database backend, using `System.Data.SQLite` to interface with the database.

When trying to create a view using a parameter, I received the following error:

> SQL logic error
>
> parameters are not allowed in views

How can I protect my code against SQL injection if parameters are not allowed?

Comment: Well, users shouldn't be creating views, so who exactly are you trying to prevent from injecting bad code? Set up your views ahead of time and query them with parameters.

Comment: It's a temporary view. I was only using parameters to prevent SQLite injection -- the query itself is fixed.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html): "If the 'TEMP' or 'TEMPORARY' keyword occurs in between 'CREATE' and 'VIEW' then the view that is created is only visible to the database connection that created it and is automatically deleted when the database connection is closed."

Comment: Thanks for that info on 'TEMP'/'TEMPORARY'. You don't really outline your process/flow in your post, but it just sounds like you're probably using a view for something other than its intended use.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get why any user-supplied values would be needed in a view definition. In a statement that queries the view, sure...

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code, but wouldn't a common table expression normally be more appropriate than a temporary view?

Comment: @iakobski I understand you mean a `WITH` statement. Indeed that's how my query started out. When the queries started getting too big, I refactored what was possible to fixed views. Later on, I had one query whose `WHERE` clause included `id = 1 OR id = 3 OR id = 7 OR id = 12`. The `id` values correspond to the rows selected by the user from a `DataGrid`. This clause was used more than once in the code so I decided to refactor it as well, but since the selection of `id`s is made at runtime, it can't be a fixed view. That's why I went for a temporary view.

Comment: I don't see what's the issue in this question (or why it was downvoted).  I understand views are created by the dev and not user (or the app) _generally_ but there're situations where one needs a runtime value to create a _temporary_ view.  A CTE (alive only for one query) won't work here as temporary view needs to appear in multiple queries in a short span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put parameters into a view definition:

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW mylog AS SELECT * FROM log WHERE user_id = ?; -- WRONG
```

The parameter must be a fixed constant in the SQL before parsing the SQL:

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW mylog AS SELECT * FROM log WHERE user_id = 1234; -- OK
```

If you do this, it's up to you to make sure the fixed value is safe. In the case of an integer, this is pretty straightforward, just cast the variable as an integer before formatting it into your SQL statement. A plain integer cannot introduce any content that causes SQL injection.

```
int userid = 1234;

string s = String.Format(@"CREATE TEMP VIEW mylog AS 
    SELECT * FROM log WHERE user_id = {0}", userid);
```

If you format the integer value as a numeric literal into the SQL before parsing, it's not a parameter, and it should resolve the error you got.

Alternatively, you may omit conditions from the view definition, and make the client specify conditions when they query the view:

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW mylog AS SELECT * FROM log; -- OK

SELECT * FROM mylog WHERE user_id = ?; -- OK
```